# Different form template in Form recognizer

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I have form templates but the order or the Key is unique to each form. For eg: Name in some form has "Name" while in some it has "Applicant's name" or "First Name". Can i use these different templates in one training dataset while training custom model. Post training, will the model be able to recognize the correct "key" (as in Name/Applicant name/First name) relevant to the form and extract the relevant "pair" for the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can but expect the accuracy to drop if there are more than 3-4 different form types (it really depends on how complicated the forms are).